# Data not stored in local storage. No warning or error in console

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to save some data in local storage but it's not working. No warning or error in console.

```
if(localStorage.setItem("testid", document.getElementById("testid").value)) {
    alert("done");
    }
```

Comment: thats because `localStorage.setItem("testid", document.getElementById("testid").value)` does not return anything

Comment: How do you know it's not stored in local storage? Whether "done" is alerted or not has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 4):

```
`setItem`
```

function returns nothing which means undefined hence the if condition never gets in. However it should still add the value to the local storage if you check the console tools.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25fsqb2u/) to check it.

Just try

```
localStorage.setItem("testid", document.getElementById("testid").value);
alert("Done");
```

Comment: is saying undefined, does it mean it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `localStorage.setItem("testid",document.getElementById("testid").value)` does not return anything therefore it is never showing any alert.

To make sure you have the item set you can check by retrieving it and if it is not `null` you can show the alert that it was successful

Just do:

```js
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("testid", document.getElementById("testid").value);
        if(localStorage.getItem("testid") !== null ) { alert("OK");}
        else { alert("not saved");}
    } else {
        console.log("No storage support");
    }
```

```html
<div id="testid"> "Hello there" </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using local storage, check browser support for localStorage

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    var data = document.getElementById("testid").value;
    localStorage.setItem("testid", data);
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already set the data into localstorage.
check the DOM in browser console under localstorage it is already mapped with value.

```
 if(localoStorage.getItem("testid") != null){
             alert("done");
       }
```

Test like this it will work fine:)